# MassTransit and rabbitmq retain functionality like in MQTT

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt, masstransit, mqttnet

The MQTT.net can specify the `retain` flag and retain messages and serve them later to subscribers.

My question Is there a way to implement such a thing using MassTransit and rabbitmq?

If so can someone provide a working sample code?

Comment: RabbitMQ [supports MQTT](https://www.rabbitmq.com/mqtt.html). Therefore, if you can get MassTransit to communicate with RabbitMQ via MQTT then it's theoretically possible to use retained messages. However, all the documentation about RabbitMQ & MassTransit integration I can find refers only to the AMQP protocol. There's nothing about MQTT.